# Performance loss from 15" to 21" using the same resolution?

Tags: performance, monitor

Why do I have a huge performance loss when I changed my monitor from 15" to 21"?

For example, Dirt 2 used to run with ultra settings, 4xMSAA, 1024x768 and 30 FPS. Now it only runs 25 FPS with very low settings, no AA and 1024x768. What's wrong?

My specs: Core2Duo E4600 2,4ghz, 2GB DDR 800mhz, Geforce 9800GT 512mb 256-bit, Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same resolution? 1024x768 is not a common native resolution for 21" screens.

Comment: To elaborate on what Fabian said, I would expect a 21" display these days to be 16:9, and so 1280x720 minimum. If the game is fill-rate bound, (1024 * 768) / (1280 * 720) is very close to (1000 / 30) / (1000 / 25), the speed drop you are seeing.

Answer (score 5):

The only aspect of the display that influences performance in 3D games is the resolution. The higher the resolution that needs to be displayed, the greater the number of pixels the graphics card has to calculate and the lower the performance.

If the resolution stays the same, changing displays can not influence performance. My guess is that you're running your new display at a higher resolution than the old one, which will reduce performance. You're stating that you're using the same resolution, but if that is true there should be absolutely no difference in performance.